# what the difference is const arrCopy = arr; and const arrCopy = [...arr];

Tags: javascript

I don't understand what the difference is betwee

`const arrCopy = arr;`

and

`const arrCopy = [...arr];`

Comment: Only one of them actually copies the array?

Comment: The result is same. Main difference, the reference to array is different

Comment: See [Does Javascript slice method return a shallow copy?](/q/47738344/4642212) and [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](/q/29050004/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavsScript, arrays and objects are held by reference. This means:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const arr2 = arr1;
console.log(arr1 === arr2); // true
arr2.push('d');
// arr2 and arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

With the second method (a shallow clone), the arrays are both still references, but the value is taken instead:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const arr2 = [...arr1];
console.log(arr1 === arr2); // false
arr2.push('d');
// arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']; arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

Just know with this that any objects or arrays inside of the array are still held by reference:

```js
const arr1 = [1, [2, 3], [4, 5]];
const arr2 = [...arr1];
arr2.shift();
arr2[0].push('test');
// arr1 = [1, [2, 3, 'test'], [4, 5]];
// arr2 = [[2, 3, 'test'], [4, 5]]
```

The older (non-ES6) method of shallow clones was `arr1.slice()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are giving the instance of an array a new name. In the second with the spread operator, you are creating a new array with a copy of the items within the original, but it doesn't do a deep copy.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const anotherArr = arr;
console.log(arr === anotherArr);
const copyArr = [...arr];
console.log(arr === copyArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the use cases (react context):

```
  const UserList = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    ...
    const addUser = (newUser) => {
      users.push(newUser);
      // setUsers(users); <== won't work
      setUsers([...users]);
    }
    ....
    return <UserListRenderer items={users} />
  }
```